# Unattended Fedora kickstart that works as CD/DVD *and* USB

Tags: fedora, kickstart, iso

Is it possible to create one ISO with one kickstart file that will work correctly when written to CD/DVD and as a USB?

As far as I can tell I need two separate versions as modifications are needed in isolinux.cfg (ks=) and ks.cfg (because I access the install media in %post)

It seems odd isolinux.cfg doesn't default to the root of the installation media and that kickstart doesn't have a global define for the source media device.

Or is there an alternative to kickstart?

Answer (score 1):

Pull the kickstart file off a web server on your local network.

```
ks=http://192.168.1.201/f17-ks.cfg
```

(It's highly unlikely that you *don't* have a web server on your local network...)

If you have to install lots of systems, consider using [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. USB need syslinux to be bootable. The source installation device is different too as you can see below.

Boot parameter:

CD/DVD use `"repo=cdrom:<device>"` while USB use `"repo=hd:<device>:/<path>"`.

ks.cfg file :

CD/DVD use `"cdrom"` . USB use `"harddrive --partition=hdb2 --dir=/tmp/install-tree"`